# Datatables(yajrabox) nested object display (laravel hasMany relationship )

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I have been working with this recently and it was working very well, but now I need to call a "hasMany" relation and display it in the table

This is my controller :

```
public function anyData()
{
  $posts = Test::with('cola')->select('tests.*');
  return \DataTables::eloquent($posts)->make(true);
}
```

It give me an array like this (testanyData route):

```
{
    "draw": 0,
    "recordsTotal": 1,
    "recordsFiltered": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "nombre": "Sigrid Mann",
            "descripcion": "lPcA0",
            "stock": "49",
            "imagen": "s14gN",
            "created_at": "2017-10-27 18:35:54",
            "updated_at": "2017-10-27 18:35:54",
            "cola": [
                {
                    "test_id": "1",
                    "tipo": "1",
                    "precio": "1",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "queries": [
        {
            "query": "select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `tests`) count_row_table",
            "bindings": [],
            "time": 0.6
        },
        {
            "query": "select `tests`.* from `tests`",
            "bindings": [],
            "time": 0.46
        },
        {
            "query": "select * from `precios` where `precios`.`test_id` in (?)",
            "bindings": [
                1
            ],
            "time": 0.52
        }
    ],
    "input": []
}
```

This is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  listar();
});
var listar = function () {
  var table = $('#productos').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "testanyData",
    "columns":[
      {data:'id'},
      {data:'nombre'},
      {data:'stock'},
      {data: 'cola.precio'},
      {defaultContent: "some buttons"}
    ],
    "language": idioma_esp
  });
}
```

But when I load the view, I get an alert with this :

> DataTables warning: table id=productos - Requested unknown parameter
> 'cola.precio' for row 0, column 3. For more information about this
> error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

These are my table in view :

```
<div class="row-fluid margin-body">
  <table id="productos" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Producto</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Precio</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want to display the "precio" in the th tag "Precio".

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your cola relationship is hasMany as it returns an array as indicated in the response.

`"cola": [
{
    "test_id": "1",
    "tipo": "1",
    "precio": "1",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
]`

In this regard, you should also access the data as array.

`{data: 'cola.0.precio', name: 'cola.precio'},`

Or you can use the [render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) api of dataTables.js library and loop on all possible values of cola and render it accordingly.

Comment: It works, thanks you very much this was driving me crazy